# No puedo acceder al hash usando los simbolos como llaves

Tags: array, ruby, diccionarios, hash

Tengo de respuesta lo siguiente:

```
res = {"data"=>{"id"=>"6243730bda26d379fdc894df", "name"=>"Alexander", "username"=>"nediam", "email"=>"jlamas@bsale.com.pe", "stages"=>1, "teams"=>nil}, "message"=>"", "state"=>true}
```

Quiero acceder a `res[:data]` pero me sale `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las llaves de hashes en ruby pueden ser definidas como símbolos o como strings. En tu caso está definido como string, así que deberías usar `res['data']`.
En caso que estés usando rails, podrías llegar a usar `res.with_indifferent_access` para que puedas usar indiferentemente un symbol o un string para acceder al valor de un hash.

Comment: Muchas gracias,`with_indifferent_access` me sirvió